# how to not include htaccess redirect on file coming from a AJAX POST Call

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a htaccess file like so

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /us/index.php?state=$1&city=$2 [L]
```

I have a file called getuser.php which is a php file that gets called from an AJAX call in the index.php. If i dont use a redirect the call works fine, but because of the redirect I have it interfering with the AJAX call and redirecting the getuser.php call as well from the post which just results in displaying the index.php file again on top of my current page. Is there a way to not have the redirect not inter fear with the AJAX call so it can simple display my results on my page without compromising the current redirect.

I tried to add the following which just causes the AJAX to break and not work since it is not allowuing the call to be made to the getuser.php file. Any help would be apprechiated please.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/getuser\.php
```

Comment: Can you post the complete `.htaccess` file or is this it? If it is, the problem is most likely somewhere else as your rewrite rule should not modify existing files and directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, the L flag should tell apache this is the last rule and to just go to the requested url.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/getuser\.php$ $0 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /us/index.php?state=$1&city=$2 [R=301,L]
```